# Database connection not producing the correct output, only gives me incorrect output

Tags: php, laravel

I'm try to retrieve data from a database but is keeps saying the output is way higher. I'm currently just testing it, trying to see what intellectual will produce. I want to use these values in a bar chart but I don't think I'm going about it in the most efficient way either, there's 40 questions in total.

Here is my controller

```
class ViewTeacherResults extends Controller
{
    public static function teacherResults() {
        $int1 = DB::table('checklist_teachers')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->value('int1');
        $int2 = DB::table('checklist_teachers')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->value('int2');
        $int3 = DB::table('checklist_teachers')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->value('int3');
        $int4 = DB::table('checklist_teachers')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->value('int4');
        $int5 = DB::table('checklist_teachers')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->value('int5');

        $intellectual = $int1 + $int2 + $int3 + $int4 + $int5;
        print_r($intellectual );
        return $intellectual;
    }
}
```

My database, so the int1 should be printing 2 but in the results below you can see it gives 2222 for $intellectural.
[image]
[image]

How can I change my code to product the wanted output, and is there a more efficient way get my 40 questions results for my bar graph? bar graph will have 4 bars, int variables are all for 1 of the bars.

Comment: Think it might help if i was logged in as the correct user ....

Comment: Check by printing one by one data like int1 and so on, are you producing some result on each one?

Comment: I think you should just run one query to get all columns of the user and then run some math in PHP. Eventually use SUM function in MySQL query. It is not efficient to run separate queries to get just one column each time.

Comment: @Robert Yes I thought so but I don't know how to code that, at the moment I have a query for each table element, so that's 40 in total ... I dont know php/laravel well enough to make it more clean.

Comment: A table with "numbered" column names smells like a design fail to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CBroe that this is a design fail. But if you absolutely have to do this, then do the hard work in your Teacher Model instead.

App/Models/Teacher

```
public function getIntellect() { 
    return $this->int1 + $this->int2 + $this->int3 // continue ad nauseam
}
```

Then rather than use a static function, load your Teacher :

```
$teacher = Teacher::where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)->first();
return $teacher->getIntellect();
```

As a side note, why associate your Teacher with your User through their name? Just associate through the user_id as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Sum your result in DB, update your class to be:

```
class ViewTeacherResults extends Controller
{
    return DB::table('checklist_teachers')
                ->select(DB::raw('(int1 + int2 + int3 + int4 + int5) as intellectual'))
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->name)
                ->value('intellectual');
}
```

**This also will reduce the number of connections with DB which will enhance the performance.**

Explanation:
The reason behind having "22222" as result is that Laravel deals with "int1", "int2", "int3" ... etc as Strings.